# How to display overlay with a spinner will the page is loading in react JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to display the overlay in react JS with an spinner when the data is loading ..
I want to display the overlay in react JS with an spinner when the data is loading ..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide some code